# Source maps for Intern

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, intern

How do I use source maps with Intern?

problem: 
 tests are using minified code by default
 if source maps are available, how can they be leveraged when using Intern?

Intern doc says they support source maps but I am not finding the steps to use source maps

Answer (score 0):

Intern's source map support should be transparent -- if source maps are present, it should pick them up. That said, the source map resolution code in the current version of Intern only loads maps that are in the same location as the source files themselves. There's a PR in to improve source map support; you can try it out with the [sourcemap-lines branch](https://github.com/theintern/intern/tree/sourcemap-lines) of Intern.